# Android: how to create drawing areas between controls

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I have an app that needs to have certain defined areas between some controls where I can draw primitive shapes (mostly rectangles).

Is there a simple control that just defines an area that I can draw on between the other controls on the page?

I originally thought that I could just draw on an ImageView, but when I do, the image view moves to an entirely different location in the layout and the size seems to get all messed up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an inner class that extends View, and put your drawing stuff inside the onDraw() method:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);   
}
```

From there you can put this View inside a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

If the way your drawing view is mixed with your controls is complicated, then you could just add your controls inside the onDraw as well, and listen to onTouch events to figure out when they are pressed.

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what all the online documentation basically gives me.  I'm just amazed that there isn't a simple way to define a canvas area in between the rest of your controls in an XML layout where you can grab the canvas and draw on it.

Comment: Well, that's basically what you would be doing when you put your LinearLayout (that your custom View is added to) into the XML layout.

Of course you could make a custom drawing View interface that you could use in your XML layouts, but it would basically be doing the same thing.